# d3.js - how to arrange the `squre` box around the `circle` properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to arrange the `squares` around the `circle` but i am unable to get the correct output.

Can any one help me?

```js
// largely based on http://bl.ocks.org/4063550

// some made-up data
var data = [2,2,2,2,2,2];

// tree-ify our fake data
var dataTree = {
    children: data.map(function(d) { return { size: d }; })
};

// basic settings
var w = 300,
    h = 300,
    maxRadius = 75;


// size scale for data
var radiusScale = d3.scale.sqrt().domain([0, d3.max(data)]).range([0, maxRadius]);

// determine the appropriate radius for the circle
var roughCircumference = d3.sum(data.map(radiusScale)) * 2,
    radius = roughCircumference / (Math.PI * 2);

// make a radial tree layout
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([360, radius])
    .separation(function(a, b) {
        return radiusScale(a.size) + radiusScale(b.size);
    });

// make the svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w )
    .attr("height", h )
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w / 2 ) + "," + (h /2) + ")");

var c = svg.append('circle').attr({r:75})

// apply the layout to the data
var nodes = tree.nodes(dataTree);

// create dom elements for the node
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes.slice(1)) // cut out the root node, we don't need it
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          console.log(d.x);
          return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ") translate(" + d.y + ")";
      })

node.append("rect")
    .attr({
    width: 25,
    height:25,
    fill : 'red',
    "transform":function(d) {
         return "rotate(" + (-1 * d.x + 90) + ") translate(" +0+ ")";
      }
});
node.append("text")
.attr({"transform":function(d) {
         return "rotate(" + (-1 * d.x + 90) + ")";
      },
       "text-anchor": "middle"
      })
.text("testing a word");
```

```css
svg {
    border:1px solid gray;
}

circle {
   fill: steelblue;
   stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I am looking the output like this:

[image: expecting result]

Comment: You need to phrase your questions better. What sort of output do you expect? We would need more details about what you want if you expect any sort of help.

Comment: let me add the output what i require.

Comment: @SiddharthShukla - added a image for my requirement.  I agree some calucation is missing here.

Comment: This is the third question you're asking today about this issue. For the arrangement I've already pointed you to a question that does exactly the same thing. Could you please explain how you are "unable to get the correct output"?

Comment: I am not able to position the squres based on the center point of the circle.  i am sorry to repeating the question with multiple requirement. since if i am not create a logic it will happen. I am hurry to integrate in to project since i am running out of time to understand.

Comment: Is the solution what you were looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sample code to work with.
I have assumed 8 nodes to be plotted so that the circle can be divided into 8 segments. Each square to placed at the distance of Pi/4 radians. You can compute the x,y as x*Sin , y* Cos. Then you will need to transform the rectangle to centre at x,y rather than the top left corner.

```js
// largely based on http://bl.ocks.org/4063550

// some made-up data
var data = [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2];

// tree-ify our fake data
var dataTree = {
    children: data.map(function(d) { return { size: d }; })
};

// basic settings
var w = 300,
    h = 300,
    maxRadius = 75;


// size scale for data
var radiusScale = d3.scale.sqrt().domain([0, d3.max(data)]).range([0, maxRadius]);

// determine the appropriate radius for the circle
var roughCircumference = d3.sum(data.map(radiusScale)) * 2,
    radius = roughCircumference / (Math.PI * 2);

// make a radial tree layout
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([360, radius])
    .separation(function(a, b) {
        return radiusScale(a.size) + radiusScale(b.size);
    });

// make the svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w )
    .attr("height", h )
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w / 2 ) + "," + (h /2) + ")");

var c = svg.append('circle').attr({r:75})
var r = 75;
// apply the layout to the data
var nodes = tree.nodes(dataTree);

// create dom elements for the node
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes.slice(1)) // cut out the root node, we don't need it
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d,i) {         
          return "translate(" + (r * Math.sin(Math.PI * i * 0.25)) + "," + (r * Math.cos(Math.PI * i * 0.25)) + ")";
      })

node.append("rect")
    .attr({
    width: 25,
    height:25,
    fill : 'red',
    "transform":function(d) {
         return "translate(" +(-12.5)+ ","+ (-12.5) + ")";
      }
});
node.append("text")
.attr({"transform":function(d) {
         return "rotate(" + (-1 * d.x + 90) + ")";
      },
       "text-anchor": "middle"
      })
.text("testing a word");
```

```css
svg {
    border:1px solid gray;
}

circle {
   fill: steelblue;
   stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a much more scalable solution than mine. :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ae9Lvjq/).
Okay, so this was basically some pixel level trial-and-error `translate` manipulation. This is for `node`.

```
.attr("transform", function(d) {
          console.log(d.x);
          return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ") translate(" + (d.y - 65 ) + ")";
      })
```

and this for `rect`:

```
.attr({
    width: 25,
    height:25,
    fill : 'red',
    "transform":function(d) {
         return "rotate(" + -(d.x - 90) + ") translate(" +(-10)+ ","+ (-10) + ")";
      }
});
```

Comment: Yes it's works. instead of hard code the values, can you show me the calculation. may be the values may vary in circles.

Comment: I'm afraid, this was a result of trial-and-error manipulation. Here's a nice article about how `transform` works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform