# How to change the alignment of circles in packed circle d3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm trying to change the alignment of the circle so that I can see the text in the middle Just like in this image.

[image]

I need help on how to align all the circles towards the circumference of the outer circle. I tried to add the text but it is overlapping with the circle in the center. Is it possible to change the alignment of the circle?

My code is mentioned below.

```js
var root = {
            "name": "flare",
            "threat_level": "High",
            "size": 15000,
            "children": [{
                    "name": "Ghost",
                    "threat_level": "High",
                    "size": 1200
                },
                {
                    "name": "Wiper",
                    "threat_level": "Medium",
                    "size": 1330
                },
                {
                    "name": "PowerLiks",
                    "threat_level": "Medium",
                    "size": 1333
                },
                {
                    "name": "Fareit",
                    "threat_level": "Medium",
                    "size": 1300
                },
                {
                    "name": "Tribe",
                    "threat_level": "High",
                    "size": 1330
                },
                {
                    "name": "Oilrig",
                    "threat_level": "High",
                    "size": 1330
                }
            ]
        }

        var svg = d3.select("svg"),
            margin = 20,
            diameter = +svg.attr("width"),
            g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

        const color = (type) => type == 'High' ? '#F72047' : (type == 'Medium' ? '#FFFFFF' : '#fff0') //colorScale
        var defs = svg.append("defs");
        var levels = ['High', 'Medium', 'Low']
        levels.forEach((d) => {
            //Create a radial Sun-like gradient
            defs.append("radialGradient")
                .attr("id", "sun-gradient_" + d)
                .selectAll("stop")
                .data([{
                        offset: "0%",
                        color: "#1A1D27"
                    },
                    {
                        offset: "80%",
                        color: "#1A1D27"
                    },
                    {
                        offset: "100%",
                        color: d == 'High' ? "#CB1F40" : "#959595"
                    }
                ])
                .enter().append("stop")
                .attr("offset", function (d) {
                    return d.offset;
                })
                .attr("stop-color", function (d) {
                    return d.color;
                });
            // .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);
        })
        var pack = d3.pack()
            .size([diameter - margin, diameter - margin])
            .padding(50);

        root = d3.hierarchy(root)
            .sum(function (d) {
                return d.size;
            })
            .sort(function (a, b) {
                return b.value - a.value;
            });

        var focus = root,
            nodes = pack(root).descendants(),
            view;

        var circle = g.selectAll("circle")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", function (d) {
                return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root";
            })
            .style("fill", (d) => `url(#${'sun-gradient_' +  d.data.threat_level})`)
            .style('stroke', (d) => color(d.data.threat_level))
            .style('stroke-width', 1)
            .on("click", function (e, d) {
                if (focus !== d) zoom(d);
                e.stopPropagation();
            });

        var text = g.selectAll("text")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.parent === root ? d.data.name : d.data.size;
            })
            .style('font-family', 'Metropolis Bold')
            .style('font-size', (d) => d.parent === root ? '12px' : '24px')
            .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .style('fill', (d) => d.parent === root ? '#FFFFFF' : '#F72047')
            .style('text-transform', 'uppercase')

        var node = g.selectAll("circle,text");

        svg
            .style("background", color(-1))
            .on("click", function () {
                zoom(root);
            });

        zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);

        function zoom(d) {
            var focus0 = focus;
            focus = d;

            var transition = d3.transition()
                .duration(750)
                .tween("zoom", function (d) {
                    var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + margin]);
                    return function (t) {
                        zoomTo(i(t));
                    };
                });

            transition.selectAll("text")
                .filter(function (d) {
                    return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline";
                })
                .style("fill-opacity", function (d) {
                    return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0;
                })
                .on("start", function (d) {
                    if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline";
                })
                .on("end", function (d) {
                    if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none";
                });
        }

        function zoomTo(v) {
            var k = diameter / v[2];
            view = v;
            node.attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")";
            });
            circle.attr("r", function (d) {
                return d.r * k;
            });
        }
```

```html
<svg width="600" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This question needs more information. Why do you use `d3.pack()`. How should the layout arrange more circles. Should they really pack or be organized nicely around the circumference of the outer circle.

Comment: Tips: group the text and circle with a `g` element together and translate that instead of `nodes`. Do not use `forEach`, use `data` and `enter` instead to create your radial gradients.

Comment: I took from this example, http://using-d3js.com/06_05_packs.html . The circles should be around the circumference of the outer circle. @wasserholz

Comment: As @wasserholz asked - why use `d3.pack()` ? Your target image appears to place the inner circles at 60 degree intervals. Perhaps you don't want the pack layout and want to specify the intervals of the inner circles ? - this would be a different answer to overriding the outcome of using a layout algorithm...

Comment: d3.pack is fairly incompatible with this when dealing with non-trivial packing solutions (only a few nodes of similar sizes where we can be fairly sure that each packed circle touches the edge of or has an unobstructed view of the bounding circle). In trivial cases, we could do this tweaking the output of d3.pack. However, this falls apart in most or all non-trivial packing problems: the reality is the proposed layout isn't circle packing (packing circles into the smallest possible bounding circle). Tweaking the algorithm would be more difficult than writing a new one.

Answer (score 4):

The packed circle layout is designed to take a group of objects and pack them as tightly as possible within a circle. So this isn't what you want.

### Method 1: Radial Tree Layout

If you want to arrange a set of objects evenly around the circumference of a circle with a given radius, you want something similar to a "radial tree layout". You can see an example of that in Chapter 6 of the book you linked to (*Tree, Cluster, and Radial Layouts*), though you'll not want the lines between the nodes.

There's also an example given in the answer to this question: [d3.js - how to arrange the `squre` box around the `circle` properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586434/d3-js-how-to-arrange-the-squre-box-around-the-circle-properly)

### Method 2: Use `sin` and `cos`

Alternatively, you can divide the circumference of the circle by the number of objects you want to place, then use `sin` and `cos` to calculate their center point x and y manually.

There's an example of that here: [d3.js radially position elements around an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620278/d3-js-radially-position-elements-around-an-object)

And a variation here: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/06/12/objects-around-svg-circle-d3-js/